# Is there a game camera that can immediately alert me when it sees something?

Tags: animals, electronic-gear

I want to monitor the forest behind my house for intruders, predators, and game. Mainly I'm interested in being immediately informed (by getting an alert and a picture on my smartphone) when there is something moving in the woods. Are there any game or security cameras that can do this?

Most of the locations I would like to monitor are several hundred yards away from the house.

Also, the only cell carrier that works here is Verizon (if that makes any difference).

Comment: "What should I buy" questions are generally off topic. Might you be able to reword your question so that it's more along the lines of "how can I be alerted to animals or people on and around my property?" rather than "which product will do this particular thing"?

Comment: I disagree @nhinkle. He wants to know if one exists. I don't think there is too much harm in this. The answer would be (potentially) **yes**, *here's some examples*.

Comment: @Liam http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

Comment: Yes true @nhinkle but I do counter that with [On questions about equipment comparison / shopping recommendations](http://meta.outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/506/2766).

Comment: Is the place where you are planning to setup these cameras on your private property? Otherwise putting up (any kind of) surveillance equipment there is pretty certainly prohibited or at least regulated.

Comment: Yes, the forest is on my own property, so that won't be an issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an outdoor camera([Arlo Go](http://www.arlo.com/en-us/landing/Arlo-Verizon/?cid=us-arlo-go-srch&utm_source=search&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=q417-us-arlo-go-search&gclid=CjwKCAiA0IXQBRA2EiwAMODilzFQn8VhrIK0CTquazqPtqPtP-1N2RRgYhKqXLOL37cn674Y106Y7BoCTUoQAvD_BwE)) made specifically for Verizon network(This is not a trail camera). It uses the 4G LTZ network and will work with a solar panel, so running power would not be an issue. This camera and plan also come with Free cloud storage.

This Camera works great but I am not sure as to if it will send you notifications that detect movement.

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm looking for. Thanks. It doesn't look like it can send alerts, but it can store a history, and that's good enough.

Answer (score 7):

There are game cameras that can send an mms or use gprs to email the picture/video, see for instance this [manual](http://z-aim.com/produktfiler/MMS%20scouting%20cameras%20english%20mannual%20.pdf) for one example.

Another option might be wifi cameras and repeater(s) to extend the range or use directional wifi antennas on the cameras, but I feel this is more dependent on the terrain between where you wish to have the camera and the resulting image.